# CakePHP find WHERE NOT EQUAL

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

can you see the error guys ? my AND conditions is ignored! I'm getting so frustrated with those arrays..

```
 $transaction_query = $this->Transaction->find('all',
                [
                    'limit' => $countList,
                    'fields' => ['Transaction.client_id','Transaction.name','Transaction.created','Transaction.message_id','Transaction.credit'],
                    'conditions' => ['Transaction.id' => $client_id],
                    'AND' => ['Transaction.name !=' => 'Facturation']
                ]);
```

Comment: Can you please provide details on the misbehaviour you encounter?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your conditions need to be `['Transaction.id' => $client_id, 'Transaction.name !=' => 'Facturation']`. Multiple conditions of the `conditions` array are interpreted as 'AND' conditions.

So your query would look like:-

```
$transaction_query = $this->Transaction->find('all',
    [
        'limit' => $countList,
        'fields' => [
            'Transaction.client_id',
            'Transaction.name',
            'Transaction.created',
            'Transaction.message_id',
            'Transaction.credit'
        ],
        'conditions' => [
            'Transaction.id' => $client_id, 
            'Transaction.name !=' => 'Facturation'
        ]
    ]
);
```

You only need to index by `and` if you have duplicate condition array keys; this is not the case in your example as you have `Transaction.id` and `Transaction.name !=`. Regardless, the `and` index would need to be an index inside the `conditions` array, not a sibling.

Answer (score 4):

```
 $this->Transaction->find( 'all', array(
'limit' => $countList, 
'fields' => ['Transaction.client_id','Transaction.name','Transaction.created','Transaction.message_id','Transaction.credit'],
'conditions' => array("not" => array ( 'Transaction.id'  => $client_id)),
'AND' => array('not' => ('Transaction.name ' => 'Facturation')));
```

In case if you want that name should not be any one of them then you should write query as follows:

```
$this->Transaction->find('all', array('conditions' => array('NOT' => array('Transaction.name' => array('a','aa','aaa')))));
```